# Set an authenticated user's email as a variable name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am creating a ToDo app using firebase authentication. I am using the local  storage to store my todo items. The problem is I get the same todo items regardless of the user logged in.  How to have make a seperate storage for each user?

The reason I am getting the same value is because I am saving the todo items in a variable name "items". I want to set this variable name as the email of the current user logged in.

I am a beginner in ReactJS and JavaScript. I am just fiddling around. I know I can use a firebase db to solve this problem. But I want a solution to this problem not an alternative.

Using {currentUser && currentUser.email} I get the email of the current user.

Currently I have an array

```
var items = [];
```

I want -

```
var {currentUser && currentUser.email} = [];
```

How can I achieve this? Any tips will be helpful.

Comment: you should save your `todo` against the logged-in user `uid`, then query `items` against the current `uid` [Perform simple and compound queries in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)

Comment: I am saving the todo in the localstorage and not in a firestore. I just want each user to have their own arrays.

Comment: 1) why would you save it in localstorage? 2) still recommend using the user `uid` and making it an object with the keys being the `uid`'s, values being the arr of todos

Comment: I am just learning JS and this was a problem that I encountered and I want to solve it. Its simply this, I just want to see how can it be done in local storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not an expert on FireBase, the answer that user: alphapilgrim suggests would be the way to do this.

However, just to answer add a bit about naming variables:

You can't name variables dynamically the way you have there in javascript, unless you want to do something which I personally consider a quite dodgy:

getting the global context (window on a browser) and using square bracket notation to update your variable:

```
window[currentUser && currentUser.email] = [];
```

I would advise against this, if you come across a situation where you do need to do something like this it would be better to define a local object and add dynamic properties similar to above:

```
const allItems = {};
allItems[currentUser && currentUser.email] = [];
```

Again, I would say that for your use case it is better to adjust your firebase store and query though.

Comment: in fact more logical code would probably be:

    ```const allItems = {};
    if(currentUser && currentUser.email) {
        allItems[currentUser.email] = [];
    }```

but thats another story